# Column created with label() returns no values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

this is the query

```
query = (
    select(
        User.id,
        (func.sqrt(func.pow(User.dist[0] - (-4.23), 2))).label("dist"),
    )
    .order_by("dist")
    .limit(1)
)
```

when I execute it I get the id but in place of dist I get None

Comment: A result of `None` suggests that `User.dist_x` is `NULL`.  If that isn't the case, please provide a [mre], including data and table / model strcuture.

Comment: The value does exist. Could the reason be that it's an Array column? I abstracted that part away but in reality in place of User.dist_x I'm using User.coordinate[0] where coordinate is an Array column.  @snakecharmerb

Comment: Okay turns out I was being an idiot, this query is correct thank you @snakecharmerb for pushing me in the correct direction. Since I'm using Postgres, the indexing for Array starts from 1 and I kept indexing 0, which kept returning me None (in hindsight I think it should have thrown an indexError). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This query is correct and will work, I just did not realize indexing an Array in Postgres starts at 1 and not zero. It kept returning None with no errors so I thought my query had something to do with it.